# Why android studio show "unresolved error" even though i replaced gradle build plugin code

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, oop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfRnS.png)before i replace gradle code like in the image here, some ID variables gave me "unresolved error" but after i replaced gradle code, just this (TOAST LINE) still gives me the[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRPzs.png) ERROR.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDMW4.png)

Comment: Could you hover the cursor on the red underline and see what exactly the error was?

Comment: Yes of course, i just edited the Question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is because you enter the line in Gradle.       `Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`
Replace Your line with this and it will work
**Issue in code**
Whenever you are inside the interface or click you need to pass the this@ActivityName

Comment: it gave me this message "Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Boolean was expected
"

Comment: return@setOnLongClickListener true   //(try to add this line below the toast)